# Ruby: How do I iterate over an array of hashes and return the values in a single string?

Tags: ruby, hash

Sorry if this obvious, I'm just not getting it.  If I have an array of hashes like:

```
people = [{:name => "Bob", :occupation=> "Builder"}, {:name => "Jim", :occupation =>
"Coder"}]
```

And I want to iterate over the array and output strings like: "Bob: Builder". How would I do it?  I understand how to iterate, but I'm still a little lost.  Right now, I have:

```
people.each do |person|
  person.each do |k,v|
    puts "#{v}"
  end
end
```

My problem is that I don't understand how to return both values, only each value separately.  What am I missing?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 22):

Here you go:

```
puts people.collect { |p| "#{p[:name]}: #{p[:occupation]}" }
```

Or:

```
people.each do |person|
  puts "#{person[:name]}: #{person[:occupation]}"
end
```

In answer to the more general query about accessing the values in elements within the array, you need to know that `people` is an array of hashes. Hashes have a `keys` method and `values` method which return the keys and values respectively. With this in mind, a more general solution might look something like:

```
people.each do |person|
  puts person.values.join(': ')
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This clears it up completely for me.  Thanks again!

Comment: the .collect method worked the best. The .each method caused a lot of duplication. If you want to go with the .each you'll have to nest

Answer (score 2):

Will work too:

```
people.each do |person|
  person.each do |key,value|
    print key == :name ? "#{value} : " : "#{value}\n"
  end
end
```

Output:

```
Bob : Builder
Jim : Coder
```

Answer (score 0):

Will work too:

```
people.each do |name:, occupation:|
  occupation ||= 'unemployed'
  puts "#{name} : #{occupation}"
end
```

Ruby 3+ (thanks to Leo)

```
people.each do |person|
  person => {name:, occupation:}
  occupation ||= 'unemployed'
  puts "#{name} : #{occupation}"
 end
```

Comment: I like this pattern, just wanted to point out it doesn't work in Ruby 3+ - one option is to use rightward assignment, e.g. `people.each { |person| person => { name:, occupation: }; puts "#{name} : #{occupation}" }