# iterate over an array of hashes to create data in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash

I have an array of hashes that I am trying to seed into a database.

```
shoe_array = [{:department_id=>8, :follower_id=>31}, {:department_id=>9, :follower_id=>41}, {:department_id=>4, :follower_id=>49}, {:department_id=>2, :follower_id=>58}, {:department_id=>5, :follower_id=>36}, {:department_id=>9, :follower_id=>63}, {:department_id=>2, :follower_id=>52}, {:department_id=>23, :follower_id=>26}, {:department_id=>5, :follower_id=>52}, {:department_id=>6, :follower_id=>30}]


shoe_array.each do |n, k|
  department_id = n,
  follower_id = k,
  user_id = 1

  Relationship.create!(department_id: department_id,
                       follower_id: follower_id,
                       user_id: user_id)
end
```

I'm only getting null values for both `department_id` and `follower_id`. `user_id` is working.

I have tried using `"#{n}"` and `"#{k}"`, to get the key values set to department and follower ids. I've also tried iterating over the array only using `.each do |a|` and setting `department_id: a['department_id'], follower_id a['follower_id']`

as seen here: [iterate through array of hashes in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26724347/iterate-through-array-of-hashes-in-ruby) and here :[How do I iterate over an array of hashes and return the values in a single string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23718284/how-do-i-iterate-over-an-array-of-hashes-and-return-the-values-in-a-single-strin)

but I'm only still getting null values. How can I get my values into the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`shoe_array` is an array of hashes, so you should iterate over each hash, and access each key-value pair:

```
shoe_array.each do |hash|
  department_id = hash[:department_id]
  follower_id   = hash[:follower_id]
  user_id       = 1

  Relationship.create!(
    department_id: department_id,
    follower_id:   follower_id,
    user_id:       user_id
  )
end
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work. department_id is null, while follower_id works accordingly. If I switch their positions, so follower_id is first, then follower_id is null and department_id is what it should be. It reads like it should work, I'm attempting to troubleshoot it on my end more.

Comment: @user3456978 delete commas where they are not needed (see the edit) :)

Answer (score 2):

According the documentation you can [create](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/create/class) records from an array of hashes:

Following should work (You can use `create!` as well as `create`)

```
shoe_array = [{:department_id=>8, :follower_id=>31}, {:department_id=>9, :follower_id=>41}, {:department_id=>4, :follower_id=>49}, {:department_id=>2, :follower_id=>58}, {:department_id=>5, :follower_id=>36}, {:department_id=>9, :follower_id=>63}, {:department_id=>2, :follower_id=>52}, {:department_id=>23, :follower_id=>26}, {:department_id=>5, :follower_id=>52}, {:department_id=>6, :follower_id=>30}]

Relationship.create!(shoe_array.map{|arr| arr.merge!({user_id: 1})})
```

Comment: Very cool. I wasn't aware we could directly .create with a hash or array of hashes, although another answer does the same with .new. We might also consider shortening it slightly with  Relationship.create!(shoe_array.map(&:merge!({user_id: 1}))

Answer (score 1):

Change your iteration to

```
shoe_array.each do |shoe|
  department_id = shoe[:department_id]
  follower_id = shoe[:follower_id]
```

An example that can use `|n, k|` would be either a hash or an array of arrays.  If you want to go down that route, you can call `values` on each hash in the array (assuming that the hash is consistent, meaning `department_id` always comes first before `follower_id`)

```
ids = shoe_array.map(&:values) # [[8, 31], [9, 41], [4, 49], [2, 58], [5, 36], [9, 63], [2, 52], [23, 26], [5, 52], [6, 30]]
```

Then you can just use your old code or refactor to

```
ids.each do |department_id, follower_id|
  Relationship.create!(
    department_id: department_id,
    follower_id: follower_id,
    user_id: 1
  )
end
```

Take note though that you are iterating over the array twice and will be less efficient compared to the first one.

**UPDATE**

Another option is use the array elements as is.

```
shoe_array.each do |attributes|
  relationship = Relationship.new(attributes)
  relationship.user_id = 1
  relationship.save!
end
```

Comment: Creating an array of arrays is also a valid solution. So in shoe_array.map we are going invoking each hash from the array once and in &:values we are extracting the hash values of department_id and follower_id into an array. So we now have an array of the values from the hash. We can then iterate over the array of arrays with our two values. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: added an update. just got a notification that I got downvoted for whatever reason.

Comment: Who knows why. The updated version looks like the best solution. It's concise, clear and takes advantage of our previous nomenclature.